# Conversion failure varchar to int

Tags: sql-server-2008

When running this code:

```
declare @SQL NVARCHAR(max);
declare @intFlag INT;
set @intFlag = 2;

SET @SQL = ' SELECT * into [##tmp1] 
FROM servicesstats_0511_0412 s WHERE department=''ACC''
and ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM servicesstats_0511_0412 WHERE department <> ''ACC''
and s.studentid=studentid ) = ' + @intFlag + ')';

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' SELECT * into [##tmp1] FROM servicesstats_0511_0412 s WHERE department='ACC'
>           and ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM servicesstats_0511_0412 WHERE department <> 'ACC' and s.studentid=studentid ) = ' to data type int.

servicesstats_0511_0412 will be dynamic hence the need of dynamic SQL.

My belief is that this shouldn't occur since count(*) always returns an Int. Even when casting the subquery to an Int it doesn't work. Any thing i'm missing? thanks.

Comment: Why do you need dynamic SQL (see Richard's answer)?

Comment: Because servicesstats_0511_0412 will be dynamic

Comment: Please include such relevant information in your question next time.

Comment: No problem. Will do :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`int` has higher [datatype precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) than `[n]varchar` so you need to cast the `int` explicitly to `[n]varchar` in the string concatenation to avoid the string being implicitly cast to an integer (which fails as the string is not numeric)

```
SET @SQL = N'
SELECT * into [##tmp1] 
FROM servicesstats_0511_0412 s 
WHERE department=''ACC''
AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM servicesstats_0511_0412 
      WHERE department <> ''ACC'' and s.studentid=studentid )
         = ' + CAST(@intFlag AS NVARCHAR(11)) + N')';
```

or don't concatenate it at all and pass it in as a parameter to `sp_executesql` instead.

```
SET @SQL = N'
SELECT * into [##tmp1] 
FROM servicesstats_0511_0412 s 
WHERE department=''ACC''
AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM servicesstats_0511_0412 
      WHERE department <> ''ACC'' and s.studentid=studentid ) = @intFlag)';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@intFlag INT', @intFlag = @intFlag
```

Comment: Excellent thank you Martin. I chose the second way since it looks cleaner. Second parameter is type, third parameter is value being passed, but why do you have to pass it like so var = value ?

Comment: It's less ambiguous when you have a longer list, otherwise as with SP parameters you can omit the name and list them in the correct sequence, i.e. `EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@intFlag INT', @intFlag`

Answer (score 2):

While Martin has answered your question completely, I don't see why you would need dynamic SQL here at all.

```
declare @intFlag INT;
set @intFlag = 2;

SELECT *
into [##tmp1]
FROM servicesstats_0511_0412 s
WHERE department='ACC'
  and (SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM servicesstats_0511_0412
      WHERE department <> 'ACC' and s.studentid=studentid ) = @intFlag;
```

Perhaps you missed the forest for the trees?

Comment: servicesstats_0511_0412 will be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not count(*) here

```
declare @intFlag INT;  change -to    declare @intFlag varchar(20)='2'
```

Or

```
SET @SQL = ' SELECT * into [##tmp1] 
FROM servicesstats_0511_0412 s WHERE department=''ACC''
and ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM servicesstats_0511_0412 WHERE department <> ''ACC'' and s.studentid=studentid ) = ' +CONVERT(varchar(100),@intFlag) + ')';
```